# How to save user id value from database on server?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have login/signup routes where I save a user to database. Every user has its own page where he can customize eveything. For example user changes his status. Status component makes ajax call to my server, and then my server tries to find a user from the curent session (I do not know how to do that) and then changes his status property in db.

I'm using React, Express, Mongoose.

I thought I coul'd save a user to my req object on /login or /signup route but this doesn't work.

```
api.get('/login', (req) => {
     ...getting data from req obj

     req.user = user

     ...doing other things
  });
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  `req` contains data coming *in*.  You typically use that object, rather than assign to it which is what you are doing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The req object contains data coming in from the http call.

For example if your react app made a GET request to this url

```
http://localhost/user/123
```

and you had defined a route in your express app  like this

```
router.get('user/:id', getUser());
```

then you can access this request object to get the user id in the http url param.

```
function getUser(req, res) {

     let user_id = req.params.id

}
```

with that user_id you can find a user in the mongodb using mongoose like this.

```
function getUser(req, res) {

    let user_id = req.params.id;

    User.findOne({'_id': user_id}, (err, user) => {

        if(err) {
            return res.json(err);
        }

        return res.json(user);

    });

}
```

or you can update a user object

```
    function update(req, res) {

    let user_id = req.params.id;
    let avatar_url = req.body.avtar;

    User.findOne({ '_id': user_id }, (err, user) => {

        if (err) {
            return res.json(err);
        }

        user.avatar = avatar_url;

        user.save((err, user) => {

            if(err) {
                return res.json(err);
            }

            return res.json(user);

        })

    });

}
```

Recommend you read this to learn the basics.
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html
https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4

Comment: But how coul'd I store this user id on my server? For example an authorized user tries to change his avatar and avatar component makes ajax call to route /changedata and change avatar of CURRENT user, but I don't know which avatar I should change, because I don't know id of the user? Maybe I'm not clear, sorry if it's so.

Comment: You pass in the id of the user in the request. Either in the params or the body. Then in your changedata function you can just find the user with that id and make any changes. Have a look at the reccomended reading. And try it your self if this was helpful mark it as solved.

Comment: Any further specific questions you should mkae a new question.